# I want to do RTL LTR in my angular12 project but I'm getting error in auth.ts error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Direction'

Tags: angular, angular-material, direction

I want to do rtl and ltr in my angular12 project I have done the internationalization using ngx-translate so for Arabic I want to change the direction but I'm getting error in auth.component.ts file on [(dir)] = "directionController.textDirection"> I don't know why I'm getting this error I also install material RTL but I can't find any helping material on internet regarding apply RTL using material 12 any suggestions..?? is there's any need to import or export [dir] things in material module or any other module

```
<div class="container"   class="direction" [(dir)] = "directionController.textDirection">
  <div class="forms-container">
    <div class="signin-signup" >
     <form [formGroup]="LoginFrom" (ngSubmit)="Login()" class="sign-in-form" >
      
      <h2 class="title">{{'login' | translate}} </h2>
      <h4>{{'login_text' | translate}}</h4>
      <div class="input-field">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <input (ngModelChange)="start_validaiton_Login_Form('Username')" formControlName="Username" type="text"
          placeholder="{{'Username' | translate}}" />
          <mat-icon *ngIf="!Login_Username!.invalid && started_Login_Username" class="textbox-icon">check_circle</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="Login_Username!.invalid && started_Login_Username" class="textbox-icon error">error</mat-icon>
      </div>`
```

**auth.component.ts**

```
myItem: string;
  direction: string;
  public locale: string;
  selectedLanguage: string;

  public directionController = new TextDirectionController();
  constructor(private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService, private _AuthService: AuthService
    ,public translate: TranslateService, public cookiesservice : CookieService, private renderer: Renderer2 ) {

      
      // set text direction to body 
   // this.renderer.setAttribute(document.body, 'dir', this.directionController.textDirection); 

      const value: string = cookiesservice.get('language')
     // Register translation languages
     translate.addLangs(['en', 'ar', 'fr']);
     if(value){
      translate.setDefaultLang(value)
      translate.use(value)
      this.switchLanguage(value)
     }
     else{
      translate.setDefaultLang('en');
      translate.use('en')
      this.switchLanguage('en')
     }      
     }

     setLanguage(langCode : string) {
      if (langCode != null) {
          this.locale = langCode;
          this.direction = langCode == Language.ARABIC ? Direction.RTL : Direction.LTR;
          this.translate.setDefaultLang(<string>langCode);
      }
  };

  getDirection(): string {
      return this.direction;
  }

     //Switch language
  switchLanguage(lang: any) {
    this.direction = this.selectedLanguage == Language.ARABIC ? Direction.RTL : Direction.LTR;
    this.translate.setDefaultLang(lang);
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this.cookiesservice.set('language', lang)
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    localStorage.setItem('language', this.translate.currentLang);
    this.myItem = localStorage.getItem('language');
    console.log(localStorage);

  }
```

**TextDirectionController.ts**

```
export class TextDirectionController {

public textDirection: string;

constructor() {
    this.CheckDiriction();
}

public CheckDiriction(): void {
    const setrtlLang = localStorage.getItem('language');
    if (setrtlLang === 'ar') { // he - hebrew language
        this.textDirection = 'rtl';
    } else {
        this.textDirection = 'ltr';
    }
}
```

}

*getting help from following links*

> https://material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html

> https://medium.com/quick-code/rtl-support-in-angular-b7de22946972

Comment: use `"rtl"` instead of `Direction.RTL`, same thing for `Direction.LTR`

Comment: not working still getting error on [(dir)] = "directionController.textDirection">

Answer (score 1):

Your are defining direction as string, but assigning Direction type  data (Direction.RTL has type of Direction). So, define direction as any, or assign to direction var "rtl" instead of Direction.RTL;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).